# referencing a foreign key not working in SQL

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to reference two seperate tables to create a third table, but SQL says there's a syntax error near FOREIGN

```
import sqlite3 as db
connection = db.connect("doctor_who_database")

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS doctor_who_database(
item_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
item TEXT)""")

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS doctor_who_database2(
person_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
season TEXT,
person TEXT)""")



cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS doctor_who_database3(
id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
item TEXT,
season TEXT,
person TEXT)""")

cursor.execute("""FOREIGN KEY(item_id) REFERENCES doctor_who_database(item_id)""")
```

Comment: I don't see any syntax error... perhaps you forgot to include the traceback in your question..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields in `FOREIGN KEY` must be present in the table the FK is created upon, `item_id` is not a field in `doctor_who_database3`, also `FOREIGN KEY` is not a command in itself, it should be put in the `CREATE TABLE`, for example

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS doctor_who_database3(
id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
item TEXT,
season TEXT,
person TEXT,
FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES doctor_who_database(item_id)""")
```